# django changing a date field to integer field can't migrate

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I recently changed a date field to an integer field (the data was specified in number of months remaining rather than a date).

However all though the make migrations command works fine when I attempt to migrate this fails with a typecast error (note using postgres 9.5). Note there was only 1 instance/entry of the model, which I have also now deleted and the migrate still fails for some reason?

```
File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type date to integer
LINE 1: ...end_date_fixed" TYPE integer USING "end_date_fixed"::integer
                                                              ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 482, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 110, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 634, in _alter_field
    params,
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/Yunti/.virtualenvs/switcher5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type date to integer
LINE 1: ...end_date_fixed" TYPE integer USING "end_date_fixed"::integer
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### If the table is empty.

Do the migration in two simple steps. Step 1, drop the existing date column from the model. Step 2 add a new INTEGER column with the same column name.

### If the table is not empty.

Edit your model to change the type of end_date_fixed to integer as you have done. Do the make migrations, the open the migrations and delete everything inside `migrations[]` then replacce it with

```
 migrations.RunSQL("ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER end_date_fixed TYPE INTEGER USING EXTRACT(epoch FROM end_date_fixed)
```

Make sure that you have not made any other changes to the model when you try this method.

Comment: Thanks that worked and worked for me consistently, when I had the same error when trying to similarly change another field.  Does the inbuilt automatic migrations tool often fail with field changes. Do these normally have to be done by hand or is this example just a quirk?

Comment: No the migrations work fine most of the time but sometimes it does trip up.